# How to query Cosmos DB if array property contains any item from a given list?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

If you have an entity class like this which is stored within your cosmos db

```
public class SomeItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<string> AffectedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Within your code you receive a list of users and you have to query for all items where any of them is listed:

```
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient("https://test.local/", "Tm9LZXk=");
var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("123", "456");

// A list of users where we like to get all items, where any of them is listed in affected users.
var someUsers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => $"User {i}").ToList();

// The query that should check if any user of the above list is within affectedUsers
var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<SomeItem>()
    // How to check for any element in someUsers is within affectedUsers dynamically?
    .Where(item => item.AffectedUsers.Contains(someUsers[0]));

var definition = query.ToQueryDefinition();
var text = definition.QueryText;

Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue a little magic code based on [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) is needed:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T, U>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<U> items, Expression<Func<T, U, bool>> expression)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> comparison = p => expression.Invoke(p, item);
            predicate = predicate.Or(comparison.Expand());
        }

        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

With this method in your toolbelt you can write the query as follows:

```
var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<SomeItem>()
    .WhereAny(someUsers, (item, user) => item.AffectedUsers.Contains(user));
```

And the resulting cosmos query would be:

```
SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((((ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["AffectedUsers"], "User 1")
    OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["AffectedUsers"], "User 2"))
    OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["AffectedUsers"], "User 3"))
    OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["AffectedUsers"], "User 4"))
    OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["AffectedUsers"], "User 5"))
```