# Filter LINQ To Entities (EF Core) query by List of HashSet of String and Enum

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this Linq to Entities (EF Core) query which looks like below

```
var query = (from p in db.Samples 
               join q in db.Items on p.Id equals q.SampleId
               Where p.active = IsActive and p.Id = GivenId
               group new
               {
                p.Name,
                p.Address,
                p.Marks,
                p.LocationId,
                q.EmailId,
                q.Grade
               }
               by new 
               { q.Grade }
               into data
select new DataSummary()
{
UserName = data.Name,
Grade = data.Min(x => x.Grade),
Email = data.Min(x => x.Email,
Total = data.Sum(x => x.Marks)
}.ToList()
```

Now I have a constant List of Hashset of Grades and Location that looks like this:

```
public List<(HashSet<string> Grades, HashSet<Location> Loctions)> LocationGrades => new() 
{
  (new() { "A", "B" }, new()), // Includes all location
  (new() { "C"}, new(){
Location.Boston, //Location is Enum
Location.Maine
}
}
```

I want to get the data where if the student has grade `A` or `B` include all location and if the student has grade `C` only include Boston and Maine.

Is it possible to integrate this within the LINQ to Entities query?

Sample Table

```
| ID  | Name  | Address | Marks | LocationId  |
|-----|-------|---------|-------|-------------|
| 234 | Test  | 123 St  | 240   | 3 (Maine)   |
| 122 | Test1 | 234 St  | 300   | 5 (Texas)   |
| 142 | Test1 | 234 St  | 390   | 1 (Boston)  |
```

Items Table

```
| ID | SampelId | Grade | Email |
|----|----------|-------|-------|
| 12 | 234      | A     | a.com |
| 13 | 122      | C     | b.com |
| 14 | 142      | C     | c.com |
```

So, In the table above I shouldn't get `Texas` row but get `Boston` row as they both have Grade C but Texas does not exist in the `HashSet` combo.

Comment: Could you sketch your tables layout with 3 items per table and an example of the given input and desired output?

Comment: I created this sample query as an example. This corelates with the real query but not completely. The output is the `DataSummary` DTO and includes some calculation from the query result. The input includes an ID and IsActive. I am just not sure if we can use a local HashSet constants like above to filter out data in LINQ query.

Comment: Yes, I understood the structure, but I need some example *data* with at least 3 items of the Samples table, 3 items of the Items table and a result table that you like to retrieve from this dataset.

Comment: I added sample tables.

Comment: Structure, data and grouping doesn't really matter. I guess all OP is asking is to incorporate dynamic `Items` filter based on `LocationGrades` list.

Comment: Exactly. I am not sure this is even possible with LINQ. I tried few stuff but ran into weird errors. Not much resource online either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I got it. You have to add dynamic ORed constraints to the query based on a given list of elements. This is a little tricky, because AND can be done with using multiple `.Where()` statements, but OR not. I did [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71175417/1838048) recently against CosmosDB by using [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and the same should also work against EF.

In your case you probably of to do something like this:

```
...
into data
.WhereAny(grades, (item, grade) => item.Grade == grade)
select new DataSummary()
...
```

I think the given example doesn't match your exact case, but it allows you to define multiple ORed constraints from a given list and I think this is the missing part you're searching. Take care to use within the lambda method only definitions which are also supported by EF core. The given inner enumeration (in this example `grades`) will be iterated on the client side and can be dynamically build with everything available in C#.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will I need to use LinqKit as well to write the extension method? Also, how can I filter using the `LocationGrade` Hashset List?

Comment: Yes, you need LinqKit to be added to your project, otherwise *my* extension method wouldn't work. To use other list items within the method you have to change the first parameter of the `.WhereAny()` method. This is the collection of all items which should be ORed with the given lambda method. What you like to OR is up to you.